# Represent nested classes in a database?

Tags: .net, database, architecture, nosql

I have some nested classes, which are currently being stored in a flat file.

```
public List<Factory> Factories

public class Factory
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public List<Line> Lines
}

public class Line
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public List<Machine> Machines
}

public class Machine
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
}
```

With this current structure, it is very easy to do the following.

1. Display the list of Factories in a hierarchical data grid to the
   user (like a tree), just by iterating over the entire tree of data
   and adding formatted rows to a data grid. The user can then
   add/edit/delete any object.
2. Allow the user to reorder things, so for example, they can change
   the order of Machines within a Line for example by simply dragging
   and dropping the Machine rows around under that Line row in the data
   grid. I can then easily change the order of the Machines within that
   Line as they are all stored in a List together.
3. Find a Machine quickly in code within a Line or Factory. I only need
   to iterate over the Machines within a given Line or Factory, which
   might only be 50 Machines in total instead of the 1000's of machines
   across all Factories.

Now I'm tasked with storing this in a database (I'm considering a NoSQL document store). So my initial reaction was that there would be a table (or collection in a NoSQL document store) for the Factories, one for the Lines and one for the Machines with the unique Ids as primary keys so Machines can belong to Lines which can belong to Factories. Essentially getting rid of the nested structure above. But after thinking about it more, I'm not sure I'm on the right track, given the above points.

1. I can't just iterate over the collection of Machines and add them to
   the data grid row by row as they will no longer be in a tree
   hierarchy. In addition, as the user adds/removes Machines, they will
   end up randomly in the collection, so all the Machines from a given
   Factory and Line will no longer be together.
2. Allowing the user to reorder Machines within a Line seems
   problematic too, since there might be 50 machines in the Line the
   user is looking at, that are now randomly spready around a
   collection of 1000's of machines in the database collection.
3. Finding a Machine by Id now means iterating over the entire
   collection looking for that one. I lose the benefit of narrowing it
   down by Factory and Line first.

What makes things worse, is I have to support the legacy flat file as well as a new database system. So whatever solution I come up with has to work across both. So ideally I want to find a single data structure that can be used in either scenario.

Can anyone offer advice on architecture and design patterns that I should look into as I'm feeling a bit lost at the moment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you approach this task correctly, its not so difficult.

The key in these circumstance is to separate the concerns of displaying/manipulating the tree from that of storage/retrieval of data.

Currently you are reading from flat files and constructing the Tree. Your grid code already knows how to process the Tree and update the flat files accordingly. I assume you want to retain the same grid structure and functionality?

The only new part then is to save/retrieve the same data from a database and create the identical Tree that you did for flat files.

Step 1) is to define a Data class with abstract methods such as loadGrid() and saveGrid() and whatever else you need for searching.

Step 2) is to define a subclass for FlatFile and a subclass for DBFile, and in each of these you need to provide stub implementations for loadGrid(), saveGrid() etc.

Step 3) is to complete the FlatFile implementations of loadGrid(), saveGrid() and then test that your grid works properly. For example FlatFile::loadGrid() would read the flat file and populate your Tree. FlatFile::saveGrid() would save the updated Tree to flat file.

Now you are in the good position that your main grid code no longer "cares" about how the data is retrieved or stored.

Step 4) is to complete the DBFile implementations of loadGrid(), SaveGrid() and then test that your grid works properly.

But before you do that, you need to consider exactly what database you want and there are several choices.

The final choice depends on several factors, but a major one is the structure of your data. As you describe it there are 1:many relationships between Factory and Line and also between Line and Machine. Any rdbms such as mySQL or SQLServer is perfect for this. But in your case it would seem a NoSQL solution would also work very well, using "embedded documents" to implement the 1:many relationships. Here is an example using MongoDB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Now go ahead and complete the DBFile implementations of loadGrid(), SaveGrid() and then test that your grid still works properly. In this case DBFile::loadGrid() will read the data from the database and populate the Tree. DBFile::saveGrid() would save the updated Tree to the database.

Note by defining this loadGrid()/SaveGrid() kind of interface, you can then go ahead and add new ways to and save/retrieve your data in as many ways that you like - without having to change your grid code. All you have to do is implement loadGrid(), saveGrid() that capture the code needed for each specific situation.

I hope this helps, but feel free to seek clarifications as needed.

Comment: The problem I feel with a method like loadGrid() would be that the data would be passed off to the grid in a static way and only saved again when saveGrid() is called, which saves all the data at once. I'm trying to find a way to work between the grid and the data in a more granular way, so that when a user makes a change, the database is updated immediately, allowing other users to view the change without having to run loadGrid() again on their end to reload the entire tree of data. This is the main reason that a database has been called for. However the flat file still has to work too.

Comment: @user1227445. No that's not what I meant although I showed only the gross load and update methods. I meant you would have several methods in the interface to make updates as granular as you need. For example you could use update queries for this purpose. This may require some thought, how best to do it, but a consisted interface for both file and database is definitely the way to go.